# ETH Transaction Stuck in FAILED Status

Tags: failed-transaction

My ETH transaction is stuck.  Etherscan is showing PENDING. MetaMask is showing FAILED.  I tried to cancel it multiple times using MyEtherWallet but when I click on Generate Transaction, I don't see any Signed string to copy.

PENDING TX
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x95750627fb8293dfad20146783329aef29138ae07a626027e54450fb683ede80

[image: MetaMask Screen Shot]

Comment: Have you tried to follow their tutorial https://kb.myetherwallet.com/en/transactions/checking-or-replacing-a-tx-after-sending/#:~:text=Most%20of%20the%20time%2C%20the,cannot%20be%20canceled%20or%20replaced. ?

Comment: I did.. I get stuck at Step 6.  When I click on Generate Trasaction

Comment: I don't see any "Signed Transaction" which I can copy
Step 6. Click the ‘Generate Transaction’ button, then copy the ‘Signed transaction’, which is a long string that begins with ‘0x’.

Comment: Problem is that MetaMask is showing FAILED.  Etherscan is showing PENDING.  B/c of this stuck transactions, my other transactions are also stuck..  Nonce = 2

Comment: I was able to clear all stuck transactions by doing a "reset Account" under Advanced Settings in MetaMask

Answer (score 1):

I was able to clear all stuck transactions by doing a "reset Account" under Advanced Settings in MetaMask